# Netbeans doesn't start

Tags: release-juno, appcenter

Hi everyone I just downloaded Netbeans IDE from the appcenter and it doesn't open. The start up screen shows up as if it was trying to load and then it shuts itself up. Anyone who might know why?

When I open it on the console it shows the next message

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory (file:/usr/share/netbeans/platform18/lib/boot.jar) to field java.net.URL.handler

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a known problem between Netbeans version and the JDK version

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/1760907

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032030/netbeans-does-not-start-on-fresh-ubuntu-18-04-installation

---

### Solution

Just **remove** Netbeans (and keep reading to install it)

`sudo apt autoremove netbeans`

---

### Installing Netbeans the Flatpak Way (current version 9.0)

**Add** the Oficial PPA repo (1)

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak`

**Update**

`sudo apt update`

**Install** Flatpak

`sudo apt install flatpak`

**Add** flathub repo to flatpak

`sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`

**Install** Netbeans

`sudo flatpak install flathub org.apache.netbeans`

To **run** Netbeans
use the command:

`flatpak run org.apache.netbeans`

or use the icon in the menu

ref: https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/

https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.apache.netbeans

---

### Notes

(1): If you get command not found on `add-apt-repository`

**Install**:
`sudo apt install software-properties-common`

---

### Flatpak Q&A

https://flatpak.org/faq/